Error al ejecutar Rmarkdown tipo beamer

Error in !raw : argumento de tipo inválido Calls:  ...
knitr_options_pdf -> has_crop_tools ->  -> 
Ejecución interrumpida

Este es mi codigo:
---
title: "Taller de R"
subtitle: "Clase 1 - Introducción"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "madrid"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

